# Forwarding all DNS request in a zone to another DNS Server in Route53

Tags: domain-name-system, amazon-route53

Is there a way to forward all request from the .test domain to specific DNS server in route 53?

Comment: Can you expand a little on what you're trying to do? I assume you have a VPC defined. Have you looked at [DHCP option sets](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_DHCP_Options.html) and considered [Route53 private hosted zones](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/hosted-zones-private.html)?

Comment: We have a DNS server inside our on-premises network. This on-premises DNS server contains the .test hosted zones which is used for our test environments. I want to be able to resolve the hosts inside this zone from EC2 instances. We have direct connect so I can react our onpremises DNS server from our VPC.

Answer (score 1):

So, you are trying to resolve .test which is only defined in your on-premise datacenter (connected via directconnect)?  Amazon has a document on this at https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/how-to-set-up-dns-resolution-between-on-premises-networks-and-aws-by-using-unbound/ .

Essentially you'll have to set up your own DNS servers using the tool 'unbound', and it will be configured to send .test to your on-prem DNS server and the rest to the default VPC DNS servers. You'll then configure Amazon VPC DHCP Option Sets to define your DNS server as those 'unbound' based servers.  This also means that the availability those servers is critical to DNS resolution inside your VPC and is something you'll have to manage.